# Why SQL ignores additional spaces in the end of a string?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a code

```
DECLARE @A VARCHAR(10) = 'A'
DECLARE @B VARCHAR(10) = 'A  '

IF(@A=@B)
    SELECT 'Equal'
ELSE
    SELECT 'Not Equal'
```

Here @A and @B are not equal.

To not ignore the extra spaces at the end, I have tried

```
IF(REPLACE(@B,' ','.') = REPLACE(@A,' ','.'))
```

My questions are:

1. Why SQL treat them as equal?
2. Is there other ways to do this?

Comment: str_replace(' ','.',@B)  is that what u were trying to do?

Comment: from the dupe answer i posted: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/316626/inf-how-sql-server-compares-strings-with-trailing-spaces

Comment: Something else lurking in the wings. From the documentation for [`Len()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql): "Returns the number of characters of the specified string expression, **excluding trailing blanks**."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@A and @B *are* equal.  They are just not the same :)  When performing a string comparison, SQL Server considers all variants of a string with trailing spaces to be equal.  Further, the active collation can group additional strings together into that equivalence class.

If you want to compare two strings in a way that distinguishes trailing spaces use the like operator. eg

```
select 1
where 'a' like 'a '
```

See

[INF: How SQL Server Compares Strings with Trailing Spaces](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/316626/inf-how-sql-server-compares-strings-with-trailing-spaces)